# Manipulating Blender Objects in java

Tags: java, graphics, blender, java-3d

I have created a 3D Rubik's cube on Blender that can be rotated like a normal Rubik's cube should. I do not want to make an animation, i want to be able to move the parts of the Rubik's cube independently in java.

Is this possible? I have looked at blend2Java which hints at a solution but with no clear explanation.

I have a basic knowledge of Java3D, i just want to know if and how it is possible so I can make a Rubik's cube game.

If this is not possible, is there another way to create a solvable Rubik's cube in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There would not be any real way to do this with out animation. You have to create each cube of the rubix cube seapertly then assign there coridants to look like a rubix cube. through that you can then have it rotate togther